# Do the retarded potentials satisfy the Lorenz Gauge condition?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, gauge-theory, gauge

Every source I have ever seen derives the retarded and advanced potentials by finding the Green's functions of the inhomogeneous Lorenz gauge conditions, and I have always thought that any linear combination of retarded or advanced potentials would satisfy the Lorenz conditions, as the PDE is linear.

I am now taking my first graduate course in Electromagnetism, and my professor keeps telling me that only the addition of the advanced and retarded potentials satisfies the gauge condition, because that way they aren't violating time symmetry. This confuses me, since I don't really see how this isn't just some hand-wavy justification, especially since I can just put the integral solutions for the retarded potentials into the Lorenz gauge conditions and show that these satisfy it, at least from a mathematical standpoint.

So can anyone explain to me what my professor is saying here?

Equations of interest:

Homogenous Lorenz Guage Condition: $$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}=0$$

Inhomogenous Lorenz Gauge Condtions:
$$\nabla^2\phi-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\nabla^2\mathbf{A}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{A}}{\partial t^2}=-\mu_0\mathbf{J}$$

Comment: I'd think, like you, either would satisfy the PDE's derived from assuming the Lorentz Gauge. I can see a symmetry problem though if you don't use it. The Lorentz Gauge implies a Lorentz invariant potential 4-vector. This has some bearing also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor to explain in more detail at his or her office hours?

Comment: @R.Romero It is actually 'Lorenz' gauge as in the post.

Comment: [Lorentz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_Lorentz) and [Lorenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludvig_Lorenz) ... looks like a law firm, no?

Comment: @hft I have multiple times, he doesn't say much beyond look at the time symmetry in the gauge condition

Comment: Sorry. I get them confused. The 4-vector satisfying the Lorenz Gauge is Lorentz invariant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition

Comment: It might be worth noting that the Coulomb Gauge and the Lorentz Gauge are the same for static electric potentials.

Comment: Answering the title question. Yes as they are derived from the inhomogenous wave equation which is only valid in the lorenz gauge

Comment: Ah, poor Lorenz. Forever being erased from history in favor of a different man with a slightly more interesting name.

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. It may be helpful for you to actually include the equations of interest in your question post so we don't have to look it up and/or guess as to exactly which equations you mean. Also, if you are using a textbook like Jackson, can you provide a citation to the chapter or section of interest?

Comment: From my exam book, he writes "From the differential equation, which has a second derivative in time, the solution should be even in time". I'm not sure why A) thats true, and B) why that means the retarded potentials shouldn't satisfy the Lorenz gauge

Comment: Doesn't the Lorenz Gauge have a first order derivative of time for the scalar potential?

Answer (score -1):

Might have found a counter-example to your professor's statement.

$\nabla \cdot \vec{B}=0 \implies \vec{B}=\nabla \times \vec{A}$.

$\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{A})-\nabla^2\vec{A}=\mu_0\vec{J}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(-\nabla V -\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t})$

$\implies \nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t})-\nabla^2\vec{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t^2}=\mu_0 \vec{J}$

$\vec{E}=-\nabla V -\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0=-\nabla^2 V-\frac{\partial \cdot (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})}{\partial t}$

$\implies  \rho/\epsilon_0-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial t^2}=-\nabla^2 V-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial \cdot (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})}{\partial t}$

So rewriting Maxwell's Equations in terms of the potentials, one gets homogenous equations in the absence of sources if $G(A',V)=\nabla \cdot \vec{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$ is any constant whereas the Lorenz Gauge requires that value be 0.

Potentials $\vec{A'}$ and $V'$ yield the same fields if:

$\vec{A'}=\vec{A}+\nabla f$

$V'=V-\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.$

So the  potentials can be modified

$\nabla \cdot \vec{A'}=\nabla \cdot \vec{A}+\nabla^2 f$

$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial V'}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}$

So $G(A,V)$ remains constant so long as the l'Alembertian of $f$ is $0$.

So if $G(A,V)$ is a constant, and not necessarily $0$ as in the Lorenz Gauge, Maxwell's Equations imply that the Wave-Equation (D'Alembertian) is zero for both fields as well as the vector and scalar potentials.  Further all the PDEs remain unchanged if an $f$ is chosen as above.

Violating the Lorenz Gauge doesn't violate the symmetry of the equations.